# MySQL datediff in a select

Tags: mysql

I have 2 mySQL requests and i need to include my DATEDIFF in my first request in order to display user_dateentree but i don't know how to do ..

```
SELECT poste_nom, ups_type_contrat, serv_nom, serv_id_resp 
     FROM USER 
     INNER JOIN USER_POSTE_SERVICE 
        ON USER.user_id= USER_POSTE_SERVICE.ups_poste_id  
     INNER JOIN POSTE 
        ON USER_POSTE_SERVICE. ups_poste_id = POSTE.poste_id 
     INNER JOIN SERVICE 
        ON USER_POSTE_SERVICE.ups_id_serv = SERVICE.serv_id 
     WHERE user_id = 2
        ORDER BY user_nom ASC

SELECT FLOOR( DATEDIFF( CURDATE( ) , user_dateentree ) /365 ) 
FROM USER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do this

```
SELECT poste_nom, ups_type_contrat, serv_nom, serv_id_resp,
FLOOR( DATEDIFF( CURDATE( ) , user_dateentree ) /365 )  as 'datediff'
     FROM USER 
     INNER JOIN USER_POSTE_SERVICE 
        ON USER.user_id= USER_POSTE_SERVICE.ups_poste_id  
     INNER JOIN POSTE 
        ON USER_POSTE_SERVICE. ups_poste_id = POSTE.poste_id 
     INNER JOIN SERVICE 
        ON USER_POSTE_SERVICE.ups_id_serv = SERVICE.serv_id 
     WHERE user_id = :idSalarie 
        ORDER BY user_nom ASC
```